# Where do I find the TCP/IP stack in Process Explorer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, tcpip, tcp

I was wondering, if the TCP/IP stack is part of the kernel or running as a service? Where do I find the TCP/IP stack in sysinternals ProcExp?

Comment: I belive the TCP/IP stack is part of the kernel - why, do you want to be able to shut it down?

Comment: for example yes, but I was just curious where to find it?

Comment: `tcpip.sys` is IPv4 and `tcpip6.sys` is IPv6. They're in the `/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/drivers` dir. Since they are `.sys` drivers they will run in the kernel and probably not show up in ProcExp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP/IP stack is implemented as a driver (`tcpip.sys` for IPv4 and `tcpip6.sys` for IPv6), which means that it runs in the kernel and will not be listed as a process with ProcExp, though if it has a services viewer you will be able to find it there.

I don't have ProcExp but I do use Process Hacker (which is pretty much the same) so here is a screenshow of Process Hacker's running services viewer with the TCPIP service highlighted:

[image: Process Hacker with tcpip service highlighted]

From there you should be able to stop, start, and disable the service (you can also do that with `msconfig` under the 'Services' tab  -- for WinXP it's listed as '`TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper`')